# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Array Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get some data from my database using PHP and pass it into my jQuery file via AJAX. The page I'm trying to create is a checklist with team members. I have a dialog box which allows the user to add members to their checklist. To populate this dialog, I want to query my database and return the members who are not already associated with that list.

I have an AJAX call within a jquery file which looks as follows:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "fetch_users.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);

    }//closes success

});//closes fetch_users ajax
```

The ajax gets the PHP file to fetch the data, and will return it. I'm simply trying to log the data to the console right now. However, I receive an error of

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in"

I have other pages within my application returning the data I want without issues using the same method. Here's the PHP code

```
<?php

require_once("database_handler.php");

$listID= $_COOKIE['listID'];
$userID = $_COOKIE['User'];

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT userID FROM team WHERE listID =$listID;");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$stnt=$conn->prepare("SELECT userID FROM user WHERE userID <> $userID;");
$stnt->execute();
$users = $stnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

$final =array_diff($users, $result);

$finalUsers;

foreach($final as $value){

  $stot=$conn->prepare("SELECT firstname, surname, userID FROM user WHERE userID = $value;");
  $stot->execute();
  $finalUsers[] = $stot->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

json_encode($finalUsers);

?>
```

Any help as to where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: you lost the data param in your ajax call

Comment: I'm not passing any data into the php file, so do I need a data param?

Comment: Try to display data  `echo json_encode($finalUsers);`

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thank you so much!! :) I've never had to do that before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: "fetch_users.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    }
});
```